# Getting Error In ImageMagick of Invalid Parameter - 150?

Tags: node.js, angular, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Hi all I am using ImageMagick to convert image. But while running the server I am getting the following Error. Anyone have the answer for this? The error is below>

```
Invalid Parameter - 150

ImageMagick Error:
Error: write EOF
 events.js:377
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

 Error: write EOF
 at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)    
 Emitted 'error' event on ImageMagick instance at:
 at onwriteError (E:\git_clone\nuron_core_ns\node_modules\readable- 
stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:449:12)
at onwrite (E:\git_clone\nuron_core_ns\node_modules\readable- 
 stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:470:11)
at WritableState.onwrite (E:\git_clone\nuron_core_ns\node_modules\readable- 
 stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:180:5)
at ImageMagick.Duplexify._destroy 
(E:\git_clone\nuron_core_ns\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:190:18)
at E:\git_clone\nuron_core_ns\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:182:10
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
errno: -4095,
code: 'EOF',
syscall: 'write'
```

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error! Along with values of all parameters at the time of the error.

Comment: Error 150 is not an ImageMagick error. It is coming from some other software or your OS